# Imagemagic: How to add backgroud image to another image using C#

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I want to resize the image to custom width and height(eg: **225 X 225**). And filled the remaining area with green background to get the exact custom image size. Using .net imagemagic library.

**Fist image:**

[image]

**Resultant Image:**

[image]

Comment: In command line, you would just do `-background green -gravity center -extent WxH` where W and H are the desired dimensions. Sorry, I do not know Magick.Net